# How to record screen using Qt?

Tags: qt, screenshot, screen-recording, desktopcapturer

Its very easy to take screenshot using [Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(software)), as shwon in an official example.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-desktop-screenshot-example.html

I am interested in creating screen recorder but I could not find a Qt way for doing this.

How can I screen record using Qt?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you mean screen cast without sound,
then you could take a screen capture at a rate of 30 pictures per seconds
then put that in a vector, create a video of that and use a good encoder so you dont waste to much memory

mp4 uses H.264/x264 and works very good but you can use whatever you want...

Comment: Is this the standard and efficient way?